# using https over a public WiFi

Tags: security, networking, https

It is advisable to avoid sending sensible data, like logins credential and credit card data, over a open and unencrypted WiFi connections because all that data are broadcasted in the clear and someone can intercept them.

The WPA2 should solve this :

- encrypting the data
- password protection

Are https protocol, that is an http+encryption, solving the security problem also on an public WiFi connection ?

Comment: Yes, probably better. Certainly the early wifi security protocols weren't much good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little bit unclear but I'll give it a try.

Even if there is WPA2 protection data could be still intercepted. If you have the SSID and Passphrase of the WLAN you can get the PSK, therefore using a program like Wireshark if you are able to capture the 4 handshake EAPOL packets you can see clearly all the information being transmitted. More information: https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11

As far as I know, HTTPS solve this problem in every scenario as it is HTTP over SSL so, even if the network is open and not protected at all an attacker should not be able to see clear decrypted information if it's being sent over HTTPS.